# Search for specific String Format in HTML using python and beautifulsoup given string has no tags or identifiers

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a specific string from an html format. The string I attempting to get is the formatted "Trucks: 1       Drivers: 1." However, I am having trouble doing this because my code is using class identifiers and tags to loop through the items I need. Is there a way to store the string in this html document given its format. I am using Python with the beautifulsoup.

```html
<div class="well well-sm">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <a href="referenc.html" title="Cruz Trucking USDOT 1953042 Dallas, Texas Trucking Company " target="_blank" itemprop="url">
      <span itemprop="name"><b>CRUZ TRUCKING</b></span></u></a><br>
   <span itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress"><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=11700+AUDELIA+RD+APT+614,DALLAS,TX+75243&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;z=8&amp;iwloc=addr" target="_blank">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">11700 AUDELIA RD APT 614</span></a>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Dallas</span>,&nbsp;<span itemprop="addressRegion">TX</span>&nbsp;
        <span itemprop="postalCode">75243</span>
   </span>
   Trucks: 1        Drivers: 1
   </div>
</div>
```

```
trucking_companies = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'well well-sm'})
for item in trucking_companies:
    company = {
        'size': item.find('text', "Trucks"),
        'name': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'name'}).text if (item.find('span',{'itemprop': 'name'})) != None else "NA",
        'street address': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress'}).text if (item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress'})) != None else "NA",
        'city': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressLocality'}).text if (item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressLocality'})) != None else "NA",
        'state': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressRegion'}).text if (item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressRegion'})) != None else "NA",
        'zip': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'postalCode'}).text if (item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'postalCode'})) != None else "NA",
        'phone': item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'telephone'}).text if (item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'telephone'})) != None else "NA",
        'fax': item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'}).text if (item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'})) != None else "NA",
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to access the last tag under the class `well well-sm`  - which is the desired output.

```
for item in trucking_companies:
    print(list(item.stripped_strings)[-1])
```

EDIT: Try searching for the tag by it's text:

```
for item in trucking_companies:
    print(item.find(text=lambda t: "Trucks" and "Drivers" in t))
```

Comment: So it worked when I used the 6th tag, however, it seems that not all of the html class well well-sm have the same number of tags. I'm currently stuck on the same thing. I would need to find a way to access that specific type of information using python and beautifulsoup